# ASP.NET Core memory consumption while uploading a file to Azure Blob

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

When I upload a file to an Azure Blob, the memory consumption seems quite high. The data below is from a 200 MB file upload.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PostFile(IFormFile file)
{
    var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

    using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        -> Memory used: 108 MB

        await file.CopyToAsync(stream);

        -> Memory used: 308 MB

        await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);

        -> Memory used: 988 MB
    }
}
```

Since the file is already loaded in the stream, I cannot understand the sharp increase in consumed memory caused by UploadFromStreamAsync(). I am using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage 8.1.4 and .NET Core 1.1.

Am I doing anything wrong or is this expected behavior?

Comment: Why not directly calling `await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(file.OpenReadStream())` instead of first writing it to the file? Assuming you use Windows (dunno about Linux) it's known fact that it tries to read the file into memory first while its still writing it to the disk

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It works, but the memory consumption is the same, except that it now goes from 108 MB to 988 MB in the single call.

Comment: According to your description, I have created a test demo on my computer. My .net core version is 1.1 and storage SDK version is 8.1.4. And I upload a 224.5 video to the blob storage. It just takes 243 memory usage. I couldn't repro your issue. Could you please create a test demo and give me a github link to reproduce your issue? This is my code link:http://imgur.com/a/0E5zm and  this is the memory usage link:http://imgur.com/siu5q32

Comment: I have created a repository here: https://github.com/andreasnauta/test-asp-core-memory. We have tried on two different computers and are getting the same memory consumption mentioned in the readme.md file. Visual Studio is set to Release mode, but maybe something else is off since you are getting low memory consumption.

Comment: I am currently debugging the same issue and when using UploadFromStreamAsync I'm getting 5x size in memory usage..  All .Net Core 1.1 is MVC right?  [@andreasnauta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1005134/andreasnauta) were you able to mitigate or have any lessons learned you could share?

Comment: @ttugates As Brando wrote, with regards to memory consumption there is a difference between WebAPI and MVC (I am still not sure why). Since Branco wrote this is expected behavior, I stopped trying to do anything about it in code and looked at my infrastructure (which is in Azure) and did some performance test (I used BlazeMeter). I can't access the test results any more, but I recall that, with our expected load, it turned out not to be a problem in the end. I have a vague memory about being able to upload more files simultaneously than I expected, but obviously you need to test that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My test application is MVC application, so it just takes  243 memory usage.

Web api application isn't as same as MVC application memory usage.

My web api application usage is 1G as below image shows:

[image]

> Am I doing anything wrong or is this expected behavior?

This is the expected behavior.

I suggest you could use take snapshot to see the heap size change information.

You could see the heap size is release but the memory usage is still 1G.

[image]